# Cardinality of the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the cardinality of the power set of a finite non-empty $N$ set is a multiple of $2$. 
Then, show that it is exactly expressed by $2^n$, where $n$ is the cardinality of $N$ and that this holds also when $N$ is empty.

Comment: Hint: How many elements does a Power-set of a set contains?

Comment: @kaka I know it contains $2^n$, but I've to prove it.

Comment: For the first part, consider the complement of an element of the power set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ :: if $X$ is finite and Card($X$) $= n$, then the card of $2^X$ ($X$'s power set) is $2^n$

$P(1)$ is obvious

$P(2)$ is pretty obvious too :)

Now assume $P(n)$ is true and let $X$ be a finite set of card $n+1$.

Let's pick a particular element of $X$, say $x$.
Now any subset of $X$ either includes $x$ or not (trivial). If it does include $x$, it is of the form $\{x\} \bigcup y$, where $y$ is a subset of $X$ that doesn't include $x$ and with cardinality $n$ (trivial).

If you write

- $Y$ the set of subsets of $X$ that don't contain $x$,
- $Z$ the set of subsets of $X$ that contain $x$, and
- $ \phi : Y \rightarrow Z$,  $y \mapsto \{x\} \bigcup y$,

you have :

- $\mathcal{P}(X) = Y \bigcup Z$ and $Y \bigcap Z = \{\} $
- $\phi$ is a bijection (one-to-one function) from $Y$ to $Z$
- Card($Y$) = Card($Z$) = $2^n$ (because of $P(n)$)

and therefore:

- Card($2^X$) = Card($Y$)+Card($Z$) = $2^{n+1}$, i.e. $P(n+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Standard proof using induction.

Assume $\vert 2^{N}\vert=2^{\vert N\vert}$ (where $2^N$ is the power set of $N$) for every set $N$ whose cardinality is $\le n$.

Now take a set $M$ with $\vert M\vert=n+1$. Split $M=N\cup\{x\}$ in two disjoint sets, taking away from $M$ a random element $x$. Now $\vert N\vert=n$ so you can apply induction, therefore $\vert 2^N\vert =2^n$.

Think of who is $2^M$: the set of all subsets of $M$. There are two kind of such subsets; those who contains $x$ and those who don't. In the first case, they belong to $2^N$, in the other case, they are just a subset of $N$ with the $x$ added. So $2^M$ is made up of two 'copies' of $2^N$, and then $\vert 2^M\vert=2\vert2^N\vert=2\cdot 2^n=2^{n+1}$, as wanted.

Comment: And the base step, using the empty set so $n=0$: this has only one subset, namely $\emptyset$ itself, hence the powerset has size $1= 2^0$.

Comment: Totally correct. I'm not sure though if you have to show a base step when you're using the strong form of induction, please correct if I'm wrong!

Comment: You still need $n=0$ to be done, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be an element of $N$. Consider the collection $A$ of all subsets of $N$ containing $x$, and the collection $B$ of all subsets of $N$ *not* containing $x$. Ther

1. $A \cup B = \text{power set of $N$}$, and
2. $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

(because every element of the power set either contains $x$ or it doesn't).

I claim that $A$ and $B$ are of equal cardinality, because there's a bijection from $A$ to $B$: take any set $P$ in $A$, and consider $P - \{x\} \in B$. For the inverse, take a set $Q \in B$ and consider $Q \cup \{x\}$.

For the second part, use induction: the power set of $N$ has cardinality twice that $B$, which is the power set of $N - \{x\}$, while the power set of $\emptyset$ has cardinality $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a set, with $|S|=n$, where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of $S$. The power set, $\mathcal{P}(S)$, is the set of all subsets of $S$. Therefore, we can think of each element of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ as containing combinations not the permutations, since sets don't consider orders) of elements of $S$. This implies that the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is equal to **the total number of possible combinations of the elements of S.**

So we have, $$\left|\mathcal{P}(S)\right|={n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+\ldots+{n\choose n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}\cdot1^{i}\cdot1^{n-i}=(1+1)^n=2^n,$$ based on the Binomial Theorem, which indicates that the sum is the expansion of $(1+1)^2$.

The empty set has no element, but its power set must have the empty set as a member. So its cardinality is $1$, and the formula holds for $2^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Vladimir Louis, **the power set contains all possible combinations of elements in S.** Therefore, $|P(S)|=\text{number of possibilities of combination}$.

Consider a string comprised of $1$'s and $0$'s, '1' at i-th position meaning i-th element in $S$ included(here we assume the set has a temporary order), '0' meaning i-th element excluded.

Hence, there are total number of $2^n$(either $1$ or $0$ in $n$ positions)  possibilities of combinations.